# PHP autoresponder HTML

Tags: php

I have an auto responder hooked up to my form. When it is submitted I need toe person to get an email with a download link. Auto responder is working great but it is only seeing plain text so the link does not work properly. How can I get it to see HTML so it understands the hyperlink?
Thanks.

```
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";

// Subject of confirmation email.
$conf_subject = 'Your Free Book';

// Who should the confirmation email be from?
$conf_sender = 'Your Book <no-reply@something.com>';

$msg = $_POST['Name'] . ",\n\nThank you for interest in our book. To Download <a href=\"http://something.com\">Click Here</a>"; 

mail( $_POST['Email'], $conf_subject, $msg, 'From: ' . $conf_sender );


}
```

Comment: You're on the right track with your `$header` property, but you're not using it in your `mail()` call.

Comment: How do I use it in my mail() call?? Marty

Comment: Drop `mail()`, use something like PHPMailer or SwiftMailer.  MIME encoding for multi-part e-mails is **extremely complicated** and not something you want to do yourself.